# awk - pattern replace and split only by first occurrence of seperator

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have 2 files, want to create a new file based on the 2 files(testfile1 & 2).By reading the first file line by line from testfile1.txt and based on string matched between special char @ and its value from testfile2.txt. More detail below.

`testfile1.txt`

```
## START :: start of file ##
path.mw.site.profiles=@mysite.mw_path@
#
path.mw.site.broker.profiles=@mysite.mw_brkr_path@
#
path.mw.site.profiles=@mysite.mw_path@
#
path.mw.site.broker.profiles=@mysite.mw_brkr_path@
## END :: end of file ##
```

`testfile2.txt`

```
mysite.mw_path=/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA1/
mysite.mw_brkr_path=/usr/local/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA2/=/mydirectory/
```

here is my command

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2; next} match($0, "@[^@]*@"){
        i=substr($0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-2 "@");
        gsub("@"i"@", a[i]);  }1 ' FS== testfile2.txt testfile1.txt
```

```
## START :: start of file ##
path.mw.site.profiles=/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA1/
#
path.mw.site.broker.profiles=/usr/local/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA2/
#
path.mw.site.profiles=/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA1/
#
path.mw.site.broker.profiles=/usr/local/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA2/
## END :: end of file ##
```

I'm getting the above output . I'm expecting the output like below.

```
## START :: start of file ##
path.mw.site.profiles=/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA1/
#
path.mw.site.broker.profiles=/usr/local/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA2/=/mydirectory/
#
path.mw.site.profiles=/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA1/
#
path.mw.site.broker.profiles=/usr/local/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA2/=/mydirectory/
## END :: end of file ##
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -F@ -v OFS= '
    # process the substitution table
    NR==FNR {
        # if it looks like a key/value pair, save it
        if (i=index($0,"="))
            a[ substr($0,1,i-1) ] = substr($0,i+1)
        # else warn about invalid line

        next
    }

    # process the template
    {
        # line has been split into fields on "@"
        # "@" come as pairs, so even fields are keys

        # warn if NF%2 != 0

        # do the substitutions
        # undefined keys are replaced with ""
        # check key exists if that is not wanted
        for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2)
            $i=a[$i]

        print
    }
' testfile2.txt testfile1.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

The file separator FS is set to `=` and *testfile2.txt* has 2 times an equals sign, that is why you are missing the third part in your output as you are only using `$2`

What you might do is remove the FS== as you don't need that for *testfile1.txt* and split on a more specific string `_path=` for *testfile2.txt*

```
awk 'FNR==NR{
  split($0, p, "_path=")
  a[p[1] "_path"] = p[2]
  next
} 
match($0, "@[^@]*@"){
  i = substr($0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-2 "@");
  gsub("@"i"@", a[i]);  
}1 ' testfile2.txt testfile1.txt
```

Output

```
# START :: start of file ##
path.mw.site.profiles=/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA1/
#
path.mw.site.broker.profiles=/usr/local/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA2/=/mydirectory/
#
path.mw.site.profiles=/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA1/
#
path.mw.site.broker.profiles=/usr/local/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA2/=/mydirectory/
## END :: end of file ##
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of splitting the input at *every* `=` character, extract the key and value in a different way.

Possible solution (among others)

```
awk 'FNR==NR{key=val=$0;sub(/=.*/,"",key);sub(/[^=]*=/,"",val);a[key]=val; next}
match($0, "@[^@]*@"){
        i=substr($0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-2 "@");
        gsub("@"i"@", a[i]);  }1 ' testfile2.txt testfile1.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions:

- if there is no match for `@some_pattern_to_match@` then leave as is

Adding a non-match entry to `testfile1.txt` (see next to last line):

```
$ cat testfile1.txt
## START :: start of file ##
path.mw.site.profiles=@mysite.mw_path@
#
path.mw.site.broker.profiles=@mysite.mw_brkr_path@
#
path.mw.site.profiles=@mysite.mw_path@
#
path.mw.site.broker.profiles=@mysite.mw_brkr_path@
#
path.mw.site.broker.profiles=@mysite.NO_MATCH@
## END :: end of file ##
```

Another `awk` idea:

```
awk '
FNR==NR { if ( n=index($0,"=") )                        # 1st file: if line includes a "=" then ...
             a[ substr($0,1,n-1) ] = substr($0,n+1)     # split and save as array index and value
          next
        }

# 2nd file: split on "@" and if we get 3 fields and the 2nd field is an index in array a[] then rewrite current line

split($0,x,"@")==3 && x[2] in a { $0 = x[1] a[x[2]] }

1                                                       # 2nd file: print current line
' testfile2.txt testfile1.txt
```

This generates:

```
## START :: start of file ##
path.mw.site.profiles=/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA1/
#
path.mw.site.broker.profiles=/usr/local/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA2/=/mydirectory/
#
path.mw.site.profiles=/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA1/
#
path.mw.site.broker.profiles=/usr/local/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA2/=/mydirectory/
#
path.mw.site.broker.profiles=@mysite.NO_MATCH@
## END :: end of file ##
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `sed` instead:

```
sed 's/=/@^/; s/^/s^@/; s/$/^g/' testfile2.txt | sed -f- testfile1.txt
```

Output:

```
## START :: start of file ##
path.mw.site.profiles=/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA1/
#
path.mw.site.broker.profiles=/usr/local/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA2/=/mydirectory/
#
path.mw.site.profiles=/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA1/
#
path.mw.site.broker.profiles=/usr/local/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA2/=/mydirectory/
## END :: end of file ##
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F'=' -v OFS='=' '
       NR==FNR{
               key="@"$1"@"; 
               sub(/^[^=]*=/,""); 
               a[key]=$0; 
               next
       } 
       $2 in a { $2=a[$2] }1
' testfile2.txt testfile1.txt 

## START :: start of file ##
path.mw.site.profiles=/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA1/
#
path.mw.site.broker.profiles=/usr/local/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA2/=/mydirectory/
#
path.mw.site.profiles=/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA1/
#
path.mw.site.broker.profiles=/usr/local/mw/mysite/cfg/DATA2/=/mydirectory/
## END :: end of file ##
```